# PopupMenu по центру Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, popup, popupmenu

Пробую после нажатия пункта меню из `Toolbar` открыть `PopupMenu`, но оно отображается только снизу, как сделать чтобы оно отображалось по центру экрана?

***Profile.java***

```
    public class Profile extends Fragment {

    private final String TAG = "log_tag";

    private CircleImageView imageView;

    private TextView tvName;
    private TextView tvEmail;
    private TextView tvPhone;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        imageView = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewAvatar);

        tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstAndLastName);
        tvEmail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
        tvPhone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.changeAvatar:
                showPopupMenu(item.getActionView());
                return true;
            case R.id.changeProfile:
                //редактировать профиль
                return true;
            case R.id.exitProfile:
                //выход из профиля
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), view);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup);

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.select_camera:
                        //открыть камеру
                        return true;
                    case R.id.select_gallery:
                        //открыть галерею
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
        popupMenu.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Непонятно, зачем вам показывать `PopupMenu` в центре экрана, если для этого есть `AlertDialog` или `Dialog`. Ну а вообще достаточно сделать так

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity, view, Gravity.CENTER);
```

Иными словами, у класса `PopupMenu` есть конструктор типа `Context, view, gravity`. Вы используете `Context, view`.

Удачного кодинга!

Comment: Забыл совсем про `AlertDialog`, если не получится реализовать через `PopupMenu`, то буду делать через `AlertDialog`.
Пробовал такой вариант - не работает.
Спасибо.

Comment: Это как? Код не работает?

Comment: Код работает, но на экране ничего не меняется.

Comment: @nikolay а попробуйте в значение View вставить главный Layout на экране, будь то LinearLayout или Relative.

Comment: @Iman Вариант с `Layout`  выдал ошибку, я потом указал `ImageView` и все заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: @nikolay а какой `Layout` вы указали?) Я говорил в самом файле, во что у вас все завернуто, ему присвоить `id` и инициализировать его как вы сделали с `ImageView` и `Textview` и там где надо будет указывать `View` указывать его) По этому `Layout`'у и будет идти центрирование. Не за что)

Comment: @Iman Я сделал как Вы мне сказали, указал корневой `FrameLayout`, присвоил id и инициализировал его, но выпала ошибка.

Comment: @nikolay странно... )

Comment: @СергейГрушин, добавьте скобки к вызову метода getActivity()